# Bone roll different in Pose and Rest Positions

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

Nice to meet you, blender community!
I know this question was already more or less asked, but I can't quite understand how to fix my issue.
So I followed a YouTube tutorial in which I created an arms rig, but realized right before rigging the fingers that my axis were pointing in the wrong way. So I went to Edit mode, recalculated the roll, and now it's fine in both Edit Mode and Pose Mode // REST POSITION. **Pose Position still has the wrong roll.** I already have the FK and IK, and I thought unbinding the mesh, correcting the roll, and re-binding it would be fine, but apparently not :(
How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Roll is an edit-mode characteristic.  It doesn't really exist in pose mode.  If you're saying that your bones rotate in pose mode, that their axes point in different directions in pose than in edit, it's either because they've been rotated, or because you have constraints that are rotating them.  If it's constraints, then the solution depends on what those constraints are, and the quickest way to communicate them would be to share a file.

Comment: @Nathan that is, if the bones are rolling in pose mode but not in rest view or edit mode, that means they are posed that way: They don’t have a zeroed Y rotation pose.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers, and sorry for my delay! What would be the best way for me to share a file @Nathan ? I'm not sure how to do it here.

Comment: Ideal host here is https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Comment: Thank you! this community is impressive :) here's he link [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Xv2NwLmX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Xv2NwLmX/)